# sklearn KFold() - save all the folds to the csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm following Jeff Heaton Deep Learning course [Course link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfOcjfIc0Nc)

and gowing with the exercises as well. In the 1st Programming Assignment, question 5, in the last task he asks to write to a csv file the output of the `KFold(5)` cross validated input data. Basically after the KFold(5) we will have 5 sets of data (train/test). What I need is to glue them together and save them in a file. I tried to do it, but my data overwrites and I only get the last fold data in my output. 
I'm starting out with Python and I guess I can't see how to make the loop to do pandas append correctly.
Link to the exercises: [Exercise 5](https://github.com/jeffheaton/t81_558_deep_learning/blob/master/pdf/t81_559_program_1.pdf)

part of my code: `df_car` is an original pandas df. `df_cars1` is a copy of `df_cars`, but I make it empty in order to later append data

```
kf = KFold(5)
#     df_cars.insert(0,'set', 'str')
df_cars.insert(1,'iteration', 0)
df_cars1 = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=df_cars.columns,index=df_cars.index)
df_cars1.dropna()

fold = 1
for train_index, validate_index in kf.split(df_cars):        
    trainDF = pd.DataFrame(df_cars.ix[train_index])
    validateDF = pd.DataFrame(df_cars.ix[validate_index])
    trainDF[['set', 'iteration']] = 'T', fold
    validateDF[['set', 'iteration']] = 'V', fold
    print("Fold #{}, Training Size: {}, Validation Size: {}".format(fold,len(trainDF),len(validateDF)))
    fold+=1
    df_cars1 = pd.concat([validateDF,trainDF])

df_cars1.to_csv("./data/auto-mpg-kfold5.csv")
print(df_cars1)
```

Sample of my output is:

```
    mpg iteration   set cylinders   displacement    horsepower  weight  acceleration    year    origin  name
319 0.997344    5   V   4   -0.705077   -0.767632   -0.506545   0.701436    80  3   mazda 626
320 1.727537    5   V   4   -0.714680   -0.322309   -0.634239   -0.206262   80  3   datsun 510 hatchback
321 1.112638    5   V   4   -0.820308   -0.767632   -0.834055   -0.133646   80  3   toyota corolla
322 2.957335    5   V   4   -1.031565   -1.029586   -1.017318   0.846667    80  3   mazda glc
```

As you see, all the values in the column `iteration` are values of `5`, meaning that only the last, the 5th KFold gets appended to `df_cars1` and I need all five folds there.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you need to indent the line `df_cars1 = pd.concat([validateDF,trainDF])`

Comment: @gnub, my mistake, wrong code copy/paste, but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in last line of your for loop

```
...
df_cars1 = pd.concat([validateDF,trainDF])
```

What this is doing is reassigning the `df_cars1` variable with the current train and validation data and the info about old iteration is lost.

Change it to:

```
df_cars1 = pd.concat([df_cars1, validateDF,trainDF])
```

So that it combines the previous folds with this one. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. It worked. It added an entire df with NaNs, but after removing them with `df_cars1.dropna(inplace=True)` the numbers are correct now.

Comment: @kuatroka Yes, because it will add the empty df in the first iteration of loop.